# Can't start neo4j console

Tags: neo4j

I used to have neo4j on a small hard drive on my machine and I created a new installation on a larger hard drive and now I can't start neo4j console. I can start neo4j shell, but console hangs up after this:

```
WARNING: Max 16384 open files allowed, minimum of 40 000 recommended. See the Neo4j manual.
Starting Neo4j Server console-mode...
Using additional JVM arguments:  -server -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dorg.neo4j.server.properties=conf/neo4j-server.properties -Djava.util.logging.config.file=conf/logging.properties -Dlog4j.configuration=file:conf/log4j.properties -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -Xms512m -Xmx30000m
2015-01-09 19:24:14.268+0000 INFO  [API] Setting startup timeout to: 120000ms based on -1
```

Any suggestions on why this may be happening? I used to get the similar Max x open files allowed warning and everythign worked fine. Any suggestions on where to look for the source of error would be great. Thanks!

Comment: It is not because of the warning about open files. But, you can take a look in the log file which is placed in the file `graph.db/messages.log`. Can you post the last few rows from that file?

Comment: Thank you!!! I found the error by looking at the log. In neo4j properties file I put GB instead of G! If you reply, to my question instead of commenting, I can mark it as accepted answer.

Comment: No probs, I added a brief answer so that people can find this question. The log file is often overlooked...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not because of the warning about open files.

But, you will definitely find the error in the log that is located in the file `graph.db/messages.log`.

Typically these types of errors is because of either:

- misconfiguration such as paths, sizes or similar
- that a store upgrade is required so you need to set the `allow_store_upgrade=true`