# neo4j can't start : Max 1024 open files allowed

Tags: neo4j

I'm using neo4j 3.2.6 in ubuntu 16.04 , when i try to start it i got this error:

```
WARNING: Max 1024 open files allowed, minimum of 40000 recommended. See the Neo4j manual.
/usr/share/neo4j/bin/neo4j: ligne 411: /var/run/neo4j/neo4j.pid: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
```

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27867951/cant-start-neo4j-console) solution but it still the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The message **WARNING: Max 1024 open files allowed, minimum of 40000 recommended. See the Neo4j manual** is a warning, not an error. It's  relative to Linux *file descriptors* and *ulimit*. See [Neo4j WARNING: Max 1024 open files allowed, minimum of 40 000 recommended. See the Neo4j manual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20924596/neo4j-warning-max-1024-open-files-allowed-minimum-of-40-000-recommended-see-t).

Is there any error message in the log ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
ulimit -u 40000
```

to increase the number of opened processes. OR

Add following lines in /etc/security/limits.conf -

```
neo4j   soft    nofile  40000
neo4j   hard    nofile  40000
```

Hope this helps